# How to set the position of the cursor in UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextview

I have an UITextView in my iPhone app which is editable.

New button is created inside the UITextView whenever user select a specific function.

As the button is always placed on the left side in the text view, I need to position the cursor on the right side of the button so that user can see what they are typing.
I can't seem to find a documented (or undocumented) method to set location of the cursor.

Does anybody have any ideas or has anybody else achieved anything similar?

Comment: Can you post an image explaining what you are trying to do?

Comment: i wish to post it too but im new here. Reputation less than 10 is not allow to post images. zzz

Answer (score 55):

I know this is VERY late, but I thought I could help people stuck in this (like me).

The `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay` seems to work fine (the other answers just wouldn't work for some strange reason):

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)inView 
{ 
[self performSelector:@selector(setCursorToBeginning:) withObject:inView afterDelay:0.01]; 
} 

- (void)setCursorToBeginning:(UITextView *)inView 
{ 
//you can change first parameter in NSMakeRange to wherever you want the cursor to move
inView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(3, 0); 
}
```

source: http://puppenspieler.tumblr.com/post/757819650/set-selectedrange-in-a-uitextview

Comment: @Cashew this is working but i don't get it, why this is working after delay and not in textViewDidBeginEditing method ? can you tell me why this is not working directly in the method...give you +1 for solution....

Comment: @Sam no idea, this is just a way I found to hack it. This might stop working as Apple updates their SDK

Comment: For Swift, to pass multiple arguments to a selector after a delay, use @Matt's delay method here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034544/dispatch-after-gcd-in-swift/24318861#24318861

Answer (score 25):

```
textView.editable = YES;
textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(2, 0);
```

Set the selectedRange to a location with length of 0 and you probably also want the textView to be editable so also set that to YES.

Answer (score 19):

Try something like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    inView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(3, 0);
});
```

This will cause selectedRange to be executed on the main thread at the beginning of the next runloop.

Answer (score 11):

I use the following to get to the beginning of the textView, using **Swift 4**:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.selectedTextRange = self.textRange(from: self.beginningOfDocument, to: self.beginningOfDocument)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

change `selectedRange` of your textView.  for example to place cursor at position 3:

`[textView setSelectedRange:NSMakeRange(3, 0)];`

In your case, added some spaces on the textView contents might helps. and observer `textview
's textDidChanged event` to prevent these space will be deleted by user.

Comment: I inserted this code in textViewDidBeginEditing but it's not working. The position of the cursor in the text view still being on the left side.

Comment: is no content inside your textView?  added some spaces before set cursor position.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make Texview placeholder is required or optional like me. See my hack

```
 func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {
        if textView.text.isEmpty {
          if self.text == "Required" || self.text == "Optional" {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
              textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(0, 0)
            });
          }
        }
      }

      func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView) {
        if CommonUtils.isEmptyString(textView.text) {
          if required {
            textView.text = "Required"
          } else {
            textView.text = "Optional"
          }
          textView.textColor = grayColor//
        }
      }

      func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
        if textView.text.isEmpty {
          if required {
            textView.text = "Required"
          } else {
            textView.text = "Optional"
          }
          textView.textColor = grayColor
          textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(0, 0)
        } else {
          if required {
            if textView.text.length > "Required".length {
              textView.text = self.text.replace("Required", withString: "")
            }
          } else {
            if textView.text.length > "Optional".length {
              textView.text = self.text.replace("Optional", withString: "")
            }
          }
          textView.textColor = blackColor//
        }
      }
```

Dont forget to register delegate: `UITextViewDelegate`

Comment: Question is not about to placeholder. Irrespective answer