# How to scroll to last character in UITextField?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I tried to rebuild the `UITextField` from Apple's "Phone" app.

I built a numpad where each button triggers a certain value (0-9, #, *) and appends it to the text field's text.

The `textAlignment` property is set to `center`. However, when inserting numbers, the text field does not scroll or move to the last character. 
F.ex., if there're more than 10 numbers and I'm adding the eleventh number, that one won't be displayed because it's off the screen.

Apple handles this issue by first shrinking the font size and then scrolling to the cursor position.

Is there a simple trick to achieve the same result?

I attached two images.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: show your textFiled configuration.

Comment: @Dharmesh Edited my question accordingly.

Comment: it looks fine. Are you changing any property programmatically?

Comment: Nothing. Just inserting the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I don't like answering my own questions, there seems to be no way around since I've just found a solution.

Alastar was partly correct; instead of using a `UITextField`, it's way simpler to use a `UILabel`.

However, the single line that did the trick for me was to set the line break mode to truncate the head:

```swift
label.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingHead
```

This way,

> The line is displayed so that the end fits in the container and the missing text at the beginning of the line is indicated by an ellipsis glyph. Although this mode works for multiline text, it is more often used for single line text.

This is the exact behaviour which Apple used in their "Phone" app (the dial screen).

Answer (score 0):

Use this example. Sets cursor and scrolls to the end of `UITextField`. Because of you do operations with UI, you have to do it in main thread

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {[weak self] in
     self?.textField.becomeFirstResponder() // to focuse on this UITextField
    let newPosition = self?.textField.endOfDocument  ?? UITextPosition()
    self?.textField.selectedTextRange = self?.textField.textRange(from: newPosition, to: newPosition)
}
```

Comment: That does not scroll to the last character.

Comment: Incredible! I don't understand you. I just now tested case and the code did it correctly – scrolled to the end of UITextField. Maybe you need to use comibned operations...

Comment: Could you elaborate on your example then, please? When do you set `selectedTextRange`? I put that right after I set the text. It doesn't scroll nowhere.

Comment: Are you using a subclass of `UITextField` now (and overriding the `canBecomeFirstResponder` property)? Otherwise, the textField won't become first responder.

Comment: Here `textField` is instance of `UITextField`.

Comment: Ok, how do you ensure that it can become first responder?

Comment: I see it on device. I create a function on button click and call it. Just for test. Becoming first responder makes textfield focused, and his cursor appears.

Comment: Strange. It doesn't work for me. I have no idea why. Anyways, I just found a solution; by using a `UILabel`, I can set `textLabel.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingHead`. That'll do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the minimum font size for the text view in storyboard and check the adjust to fit check box below it.

[image]

Comment: That's for shrinking, true. But it doesn't scroll to the last character.

Comment: have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756836/setting-uitextview-cursor-position-to-end-of-text

Answer (score 0):

why using a textfield instead of using a uilabel?

This can easily fixed with

```
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
label.textAlignment = .center
label.setFillSuperview(withPadding: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: whatYouNeed, bottom: 0, right: whatYouNeed))
```

and add extension to UIView

```
extension UIView {
    func setFillSuperview(withPadding padding: UIEdgeInsets = .zero) {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        if let superviewLeadingAnchor = superview?.leadingAnchor {
            leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superviewLeadingAnchor, constant: padding.left).isActive = true
        }

        if let superviewTrailingAnchor = superview?.trailingAnchor {
            trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superviewTrailingAnchor, constant: -padding.right).isActive = true
        }

        if let superviewBottomAnchor = superview?.bottomAnchor {
            bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superviewBottomAnchor, constant: -padding.bottom).isActive = true
        }

        if let superviewTopAnchor = superview?.topAnchor {
            topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superviewTopAnchor, constant: padding.top).isActive = true
        }
    }
```

Comment: You forgot `label.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingHead`. That did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code snippet in your viewcontroller to shrink the text as it increases.

```
func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    myTextField.minimumFontSize = 4.0
    myTextField.setNeedsLayout()
    myTextField.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right, that works as intended. That's basically what pooja suggested as well above. I'm also looking for a way to "scroll" to the last character.

Comment: If there're more than 10 to 15 characters, the font size does not shrink anymore because it is at its lowest value. Further characters get cut off then (as shown on the first image in my question), even if the font size is small.

Comment: yes defenitely when it will reach the lowest font size, will stop shrinking then it will cut of the characters but then it should show the most recent input characters just like contacts app in iOS, if its behaving like this then its perfect.

Comment: `it should show the most recent input characters` -> Exactly. Unfortunately, that's what it doesn't do.

Comment: Did you also noticed that in Contacts App the text alignment starts from right side & goes to left might be that also makes difference, kindly check that way as well

Comment: That doesn't make a difference neither. (Btw, just to clarify, I'm talking about the "Phone" app, not "Contacts").