# set the cursor position on textview

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to to set the cursor position based on the x,y coordinates on the text view.          For example I want cursor position on (10,5,300,462), I want to insert the text this frame only based on cursor.

In view did load i set the delegate and use the `NSMakeRange()` function

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
         _TextView.delegate=self;
           _TextView.editable = YES;
          [_TextView setSelectedRange:NSMakeRange(5,0)];
    }
```

I create a text view with frame of (10,22,300,462) and added to the view. My reqirement is i want display the cursor on text base on x,y coordinates x=10 after and y=5 after in the text view ...

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10135086/how-to-set-cursor-position-for-uitextview-on-user-input

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891072/how-to-set-the-position-of-the-cursor-in-uitextview

Comment: are you getting the solution?

Comment: no i am not getting the solution......

Comment: i already try that links ....

Answer (score 0):

try like this it'l work in my case it's working,

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textview 
{ 
    [self performSelector:@selector(setCursorPosition:) withObject:textview afterDelay:0.01]; 
} 

- (void)setCursorPosition:(UITextView *)textview 
{ 
    textview.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(10, 0); 
}
```

Comment: for example  textview  size is(0,0,300,421) and i want cursor position on (10,5.250,400)..remaining area cursor not works...

Answer (score 0):

hello stack overflow community.
i hope i don't answer to late.

```
- (NSUInteger) textOffsetFromPoint: (CGPoint *) position
{
    // this gives you the nearest UITextPosition
    UITextPosition * closestPosition = [textView closestPositionToPoint:tapPoint];

    // and this "translate" UITextPosition into an integer
    NSUInteger offset = [textView offsetFromPosition:textView.beginningOfDocument 
                                          toPosition:closestPosition];
    return offset;
}
```

then the code suggested by Sunny.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(setCursorPosition:) withObject:textView afterDelay:0.01];

- (void)setCursorPosition:(UITextView *)textview
{
    textview.selectedRange = NSMakeRange([self textOffsetFromPoint:position], 0);
}
```

Look UITextInput Protocol Reference for more information.