# Change cursor position when UITextView.text is nil/empty

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to position cursor after label subview in a UITextView

I can position cursor when there is some text in `UITextView` using

[How to set the position of the cursor in UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891072/how-to-set-the-position-of-the-cursor-in-uitextview)

However, if `UITextView.text` is `empty` or `nil`, it stays at the beginning

Is there a way for me to position cursor when there is no text?

I am not sure if I am requirement make sense but thats something I really want for last 10 hours.

I am trying to position cursor after label subview in a UITextView

What I want is:

- User types in TextView
- TableView is displayed with content filtered by text in TextView
- User select a cell in TableView
- I create a label with the cell content and add as subview to TextView
- I reset the textView.text = empty
- User types again in TextView and above steps repeat.
- The behavior is implemented by iMessage when we try to select contacts.

If you could suggest an alternative.

Comment: Hey did you manage to solve it?..

Comment: I went for alternate design.