# Setting UITextView's cursor position generates warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uitextview, nsrange

I've implemented a simple **drfat storage** for `UITextView` I use in application. Everything works fine, but when I retrieve this draft, assign it to the `UITextView` and set `selectedRange` (to also some stored value) I get this *weird* warning:

```
requesting caretRectForPosition: with a position beyond the NSTextStorage (4)
```

From the things I've noticed... This only happens for strings which are shorter than 4 characters (this may give some clue, because 4 also appears in the warning message).
It may be helpful ti post the actual assignment code, so here it is:

```
self.textView.text = savedDraft.text;
self.textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(savedDraft.cursorPosition, 0);
```

**Do you have any idea what can generate this kind of warning?** I've found [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/30372) that this may be caused by Swift implementation of `UITextView`, but we're pure Objective-C.

---

**Update:**

When I save I do save this `location` as `NSUInteger` and I get it from my `UITextView` like this:

```
self.textView.selectedRange.location
```

So if you consider a simple "Hi" message (two characters) I get this kind of logs form save and retrieve methods:

```
Get draft position: 0
Saving draft position: 2
Get draft position: 2
```

Comment: Try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891072/how-to-set-the-position-of-the-cursor-in-uitextview

Comment: What's the value of `savedDraft.cursorPosition` when it appears?

Comment: I think it should be savedDraft.text.cursorPosition

Comment: @Larme I've updated my question.

Comment: @Pushkraj `text` is `NSString`, so it doesn't have something like `cursosrPosition`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` is playing the big role here and when everywhing happens in `viewDidLoad` it creates conflicts.
It seems that keyboard showing also affects **caret position** and when I manually change `self.textView.selectedRange` I do it too fast, so it conflicts with this keyboard notifiaction.

For me the solution was to simply put this `selectedRange` thing in block with some really small delay like this:

```
@weakify(self)
[JDLDispatchUtils asyncOnMainAfter:0.01 block:^{
    @strongify(self)
    self.textView.text = savedDraft.text;
    self.textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(savedDraft.cursorPosition, 0);
}];
```